# Error code: BC30456 'idno' is not a member of 'IEnumerable(Of pt)'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to join 2 tables from sql server using linq to sql in vb.net web API project.

i tried this but it didn't work.

```
Dim query = (From pt In db.pt
             Join pt_v In db.pt_v On pt_v.paid Equals pt.paid
             Where pt.paid.Contains(no1) And pt.name.Contains(no2)
             Group pt By pt.paid Into grouped = Group
             Select grouped.idno, grouped.age, grouped.name)
```

But 'grouped' is underlined red saying:

> Error code: BC30456 'idno' is not a member of 'IEnumerable(Of pt)'.

And at the for each loop:

```
For Each item In query
```

'query' is also underlined red saying:

> Expression is of type '?', which is not a collection type.

**UPDATED v1**

```
Dim query = From pt In db.pt.GroupBy(Function(d) d.paid)
                            Join p_v In db.p_v On p_v.paid Equals pt.Key
                            Where p_v.paid.Contains(no1)
                            Select New With {
                                .idno = p_v.idno,
                                .age = p_v.age,
                                .name = p_v.name
                                }
```

So far there is no red underline underneath any variables, but i didn't manage to display only one of the idno. And in the 'select new with' clause, i couldn't access to pt's values unless i use the pt.ToList, but when i do so, it displays 300000++ entries. I'm sorry that i didn't explain well enough before. When i tried to access the values from table pt,

```
Select New With {
                  .idno = p_v.idno,
                  .age = pt.age,
                  .name = pt.name
                }
```

pt.name is underlined red saying 'name is not a member of IGrouping(Of String, pt)'

What i'm hoping is when i choose to display the database value based on no1, say idno has 3 entries with the same idno,

```
{.idno = 1, .age = 10, .name = someone}
{.idno = 1, .age = 12, .name = someone2}
{.idno = 1, .age = 13, .name = someone3}
```

..It only displays one of the 3.

```
{.idno = 1, .age = 10, .name = someone}
```

**UPDATED v2**

This is what i did. I reversed the arrangement of the tables because i wanted to refer more fields from pt_v table.

```
Dim query = From pt_v In db.pt_v.GroupBy(Function(d) d.paid)
                    Join pt In db.pt On pt.paid Equals pt_v.Key
                    Where pt_v.Key.Contains(no1) Or pt.pname.Contains(no2)
                    Select New With {
                                .idno = pt.idno,
                                .age = pt.age,
                                .name = pt.name,   
                                .fod = pt_v.FirstOrDefault()  'ok 
                                .pri = pt_v.Key  'only .Key worked for accessing field from pt_v table
                                .status = pt_v.status,  'underlined red
                                }
```

There is no problem when i added .fod and .pri, but the .status is not accepted saying

> 'status is not a member of IGrouping(Of String, pt)'

Comment: @Jinx88909 tried it. now the idno, age and name are not underlined red anymore, but the grouped is underlined red saying: BC36594 Definition of method 'grouped' is not accessible in this context

Comment: @Jinx88909 i wished it would be as easy as '...Group pt By pt.paid...', but when i did that, there's an error BC36615 'Into' expected

Comment: @Jinx88909 the brackets i forgot to remove from trying out .distinct().  sorry but i'm confused..what do you mean and how to reference the fields?

Comment: Please describe the tables (columns) and type the Sql equivalent statement to the Linq statement that works. The code in your question I 'm afraid is wrong.

Comment: @Jinx88909 I've tried your suggestion, but still underlined red saying: 'Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.' Thanks, please have a look at it. I'm still new to linq so i'm getting more and more confused after looking at the different ways people apply the group by query but when i tried it didn't work for me.

Comment: I'll have a look tomorrow. If you're new to Linq then it will be confusing. I haven't yet mastered the syntax myself so could potentially confuse you more. Once im back on my dev machine I'll have a proper look. (I'm going to delete my previous comments for now as it's cluttering the question and don't provide any help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to clarify your post and add more info about input data (tables) and also what you expect as result.

I can't understand what are you asking of but I 'm pretty sure you need to read more about linq.

Maybe this example will help you understand how join and group by works:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim orders As New List(Of Order) From {
            New Order() With {.Id = 1, .Description = "first order"},
            New Order() With {.Id = 2, .Description = "second order"}
        }

        Dim details As New List(Of OrderDetail) From {
            New OrderDetail() With {.Id = 1, .OrderId = 1, .ProductId = 1},
            New OrderDetail() With {.Id = 2, .OrderId = 1, .ProductId = 3},
            New OrderDetail() With {.Id = 3, .OrderId = 2, .ProductId = 100},
            New OrderDetail() With {.Id = 4, .OrderId = 2, .ProductId = 15},
            New OrderDetail() With {.Id = 5, .OrderId = 2, .ProductId = 55}
        }


        Console.WriteLine("first example")
        Dim orderDetails = From g In details.GroupBy(Function(d) d.OrderId)
                           Join order In orders On order.Id Equals g.Key
                           Select New With {.Order = order, .Details = g.ToList}

        orderDetails.ToList.ForEach(Sub(orderDetail)
                                        Console.WriteLine(orderDetail.Order)

                                        orderDetail.Details.ForEach(Sub(detail)
                                                                        Console.WriteLine("  " & detail.ToString)
                                                                    End Sub)

                                        Console.WriteLine()
                                    End Sub)

        Console.WriteLine()




        Console.WriteLine("second example")
        Dim orderDetailsNew = From g In details.GroupBy(Function(d) d.OrderId)
                           Join order In orders On order.Id Equals g.Key
                           Select New With {.Order = order, .Details = New List(Of OrderDetail)() From {g.FirstOrDefault()}}


        orderDetailsNew.ToList.ForEach(Sub(orderDetail)
                                           Console.WriteLine(orderDetail.Order)

                                           orderDetail.Details.ForEach(Sub(detail)
                                                                           Console.WriteLine("  " & detail.ToString)
                                                                       End Sub)

                                           Console.WriteLine()
                                       End Sub)

        Console.WriteLine()



        Console.WriteLine("third example")
        Dim orderDetailsNew2 = From g In details.GroupBy(Function(d) d.OrderId)
                           Join order In orders On order.Id Equals g.Key
                           Where order.Id = 1
                           Select New With {.Order = order, .Detail = g.FirstOrDefault()}

        orderDetailsNew2.ToList.ForEach(Sub(orderDetail)
                                            Console.WriteLine(orderDetail.Order.ToString & " " & orderDetail.Detail.ToString)
                                        End Sub)

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Public Class Order
        Public Property Id As Integer
        Public Property Description As String

        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return String.Format("Id: {0}, Description: {1}", Id, Description)
        End Function
    End Class

    Public Class OrderDetail
        Public Property Id As Integer
        Public Property OrderId As Integer
        Public Property ProductId As Integer

        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return String.Format("Id: {0}, OrderId: {1}, ProductId: {2}", Id, OrderId, ProductId)
        End Function
    End Class

End Module
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Its really neat and i understood your example well, but the thing is, based on your example, what i hoped is  when i chose to display .OrderId=1; instead of displaying 2 values: .ProductId = 1 and .ProductId = 3, it displays only one. I've tried adding a where clause in between the join and select clause(i've updated my question on what i've done), but it still displays both .ProductId values.

Comment: @Nurul I'm just looking at this again and I'm now wondering why you are `Grouping` at all. Are you wanting to show a `Sum` or a `Count` of anything as that's what `Grouping` will do. If you just joined the two classes together without a `Group`, use a `Where` to filter on your results, you will probably see all the records. You should also join on `Ids`. I'm not use what `Paid` is in your example however look at what Shadow has done. `order.Id Equals g.Key`. `g.Key` references to `d.OrderId` in the grouping (both are Ids in his classes).

Comment: @Nurul I 'm not sure that I understood correctly what you asked for but I gave it a try. Please check my updated code example after your comment here.

Comment: @shadow thanks so much for the great answer! it worked now! :D but, just wondering because when i try to pass the value of the other fields from Details table in the select clause, it seemed like i can't access to them. It said " 'status' is not a member of 'IGrouping(Of String, g)' " Is it because i'm referencing to a table, and you're referencing a list, thats why it works for you..? so does that mean that i have to add a list for that table?

Comment: Please update your post with the code you are trying. I 'm not sure about the `status` you wrote.

Comment: @Nurul `From pt_v In db.pt_v.GroupBy(Function(d) d.paid)` returns `IGrouping(Of String, pt)`. Think of it as `Dictionary<string, List<pt>>`. By calling `pt_v.status` is something like calling `List<pt>.status`. You have to read more on LinQ or try to perform the same functionality without LinQ (something like using for each).

Comment: @shadow, I've decided to use SQL query instead because i feel its more flexible. But i'm having a bit of a problem. Could you please have a look at it for me? [This is the question link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41787038/the-data-reader-is-incompatible-with-the-specified-myproject-pt)